# Android Studio- android Layout Preview stuck loading

Tags: android-studio

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3glg3.png)

It is just stuck on loading. I have tried reinstalling it , waiting for it ,and restoring to default configurations but nothing works.